# Unable to acess SQLite database in Ubuntu using PHP under Apache

Tags: apache2, php, sqlite3

I am having trouble using SQLite3 with PHP in Ubuntu but it works well with Windows. In Ubuntu I have installed the `php-sqlite` package and the SQLite database is made using SQLite3.

Answer (score 0):

The package that you need to have installed is `php5-sqlite` [View on Ubuntu  Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-sqlite)

You can check if it's installed using a `phpinfo();` page. Like this one :

```
//phpinfo.php, show all PHP info

<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If you see the module loaded, then the issue is somewhere else. If you can't see the SQLite module, then you should check your php.ini configuration file.

Comment: I have tried everything its ok but sqlite database is not loading in my php code